# SQL conversion to Linq to entities

Tags: sql, linq-to-entities

The SQL request:

```
DECLARE @search varchar(20)
set @search = '%a%'

Select distinct top (500) 
    Customer.Number,Contact.name, Address.StreetAddress, Phone.Number, 
    Customer.Type               
from 
    Customer
left join 
    dbo.Address on dbo.Customer.ContactId  = dbo.Address.ContactId
left join 
    dbo.Contact on dbo.Customer.ContactId  = dbo.Contact.Id
left join 
    dbo.Phone on dbo.Customer.ContactId  = dbo.Phone.ContactId 
              and Phone.Sequence = 1
where 
    Customer.IsActive = 1 
    and Customer.ContactId 
        in (--Primary Contact
            SELECT  Customer.ContactId
            FROM dbo.Customer
            INNER JOIN dbo.Contact ON dbo.Contact.id = dbo.Customer.ContactId
            LEFT JOIN dbo.Email ON dbo.Customer.ContactId  = dbo.Email.ContactId
            LEFT JOIN dbo.Phone ON dbo.Customer.ContactId  = dbo.Phone.ContactId
            LEFT JOIN dbo.Address ON dbo.Customer.ContactId  = dbo.Address.ContactId
            WHERE 
                Contact.FirstNameCareOf LIKE @search
                OR Contact.Name LIKE @search
                OR Email.Address LIKE @search
                OR Phone.Number LIKE @search
                OR Address.StreetAddress LIKE @search
                OR Address.City LIKE @search
                OR Address.ZipCode LIKE @search

          union

          --Secondary Contacts
          SELECT Customer.ContactId
          FROM dbo.Customer
          INNER JOIN dbo.Relationship ON dbo.Contact.Id = dbo.Relationship.TargetContactId
          INNER JOIN dbo.Contact on dbo.Contact.id = dbo.Relationship.SourceContactId
          LEFT JOIN dbo.Email ON dbo.Contact.Id = dbo.Email.ContactId
          LEFT JOIN dbo.Phone ON dbo.Contact.Id = dbo.Phone.ContactId
          WHERE 
            Contact.FirstNameCareOf LIKE @search
            OR Contact.Name LIKE @search
            OR Email.Address LIKE @search
            OR Phone.Number LIKE @search)
order by
    Customer.Number
```

This is what I've got so far :

```
from customerTable in Customers

    join contactTable in Contacts
        on customerTable.ContactId equals contactTable.Id

    join addressTable in Addresses
        on customerTable.ContactId equals addressTable.ContactId

    // the following may no exists for the customer so we dont want to join them since the customer will not be in the request results because of this  
    //  join phoneTable in Phones
    //      on customerTable.ContactId equals phoneTable.ContactId 
    //      
    //  join emailTable in Emails
    //      on customerTable.ContactId equals emailTable.ContactId

    // alternate method to query email and phone table without effecting the results    
    let emailMatch = Emails.Where (p => p.ContactId == customerTable.ContactId && p.Address.Contains("a"))
    let phoneMatch = Phones.Where (p => p.ContactId == customerTable.ContactId && p.Number.Contains("a"))

    where customerTable.IsActive && ( contactTable.Name.Contains("a") || contactTable.FirstNameCareOf.Contains("a") ||addressTable.StreetAddress.Contains("a") || addressTable.City.Contains("a") ||    
                                          addressTable.ZipCode.Contains("a") || emailMatch.Any()|| phoneMatch.Any() )
 orderby customerTable.Number 
            select new {CustomerNumber = customerTable.Number, contactTable.Name, addressTable.StreetAddress, customerTable.Type.EnumId}
```

Questions

1. Is there an easy way to convert my SQL request to linq to entities? After a day I'm still stock playing with the linq request above
2. What is the real and most performant way to do an inner join and a left join like in my SQL request?
3. Is it make sense to try to convert the EXACT SQL request "statement" to linq? Or is it better to do it with a totally different approach in linq? I mean the most performant way to do this in SQL is not necessarily the same approach at all in linq?
4. When uncommenting the join to the phones.... it will not return any customer without phone... is it possible to return in in the result even if there is nothing to join on the phone table for that customer?

Thanks for any help or anything to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first three question are answered by: **use navigation properties.** For some reason people from a SQL background nearly always start out writing LINQ with `join` statements. This has at least three major drawbacks: the `join` statement -

- is verbose
- doesn't reveal the multiplicity of an association. The statement

  ```cs
  from customerTable in Customers
  join contactTable in Contacts ...
  ```

  doesn't tell me if Customer-Contact is `1-n`, `n-1`, or `1-1`.
- is error prone: you have to enter the join columns, and you could pick the wrong ones (I've seen it happen).

This all changes if you use properly named navigation properties, like

```cs
from cust in Customers
from cont in cust.Contacts ...
```

It is short, it shows that the association is `1-n`, and you configure the association once and never care about the join columns any more.

So if you do this, your query will be shaped like

```cs
from cust in Customers
where cust.Contacts
          .Any(cont => cont.Name.Contains("a")
                    || cont.FirstNameCareOf.Contains("a")
                    || cont.Address.StreetAddress.Contains("a")
                    || cont.Address.City.Contains("a")
                    || ...  )
   || cust.Relationships
          .Any(rel => rel.TargetContact.Name.Contains("a")
                   || rel.TargetContact.FirstNameCareOf.Contains("a")
                   || rel.TargetContact.Address.StreetAddress.Contains("a")
                   || rel.TargetContact.Address.City.Contains("a")
                   || ...  )
select cust
```

(as you see, I have to guess the multiplicity of Customer-Relationship)

This will generate a SQL query in which the main predicates consist of `EXIST` statement. I think this is better than your combination of `IN` and `DISTINCT`, because an `EXIST` is an efficient search strategy.

As for your fourth question: you can also include the matches on phones in your query, together with `|| cont.Phone == null`.

Comment: Thanks for  your help!  I was totally wrong about how to do this in linq.  Your answer really help me.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you could just use the 4 entities you're searching in and combine the results..

It's a pretty large query but as a starting point you could use.

```
var contacts = from c in Contacts
               where c.FirstNameCareOf.Contains("c") ||
                     c.Name.Contains("c")
               select c.Customer;

var emails =   from e in Emails
               where e.Address.Contains("c")
               select e.Contact.Customer;
```

Then when you have all of the customers just add them to a list.

```
var customers = new List<Customer>();
customers.AddRange(contacts);
customers.AddRange(emails);
etc..
```